# How to wait for the remote exe to complete - c#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, console-application

The code looks lengthy but it's a simple program.
I have built a console app (TakeScreenshots) that will take website screenshots from firefox, chrome & ie in that order & save them in a folder. When I manually run TakeScreenshots.exe, all 3 screenshots are saved.

Now, I have built another console app (MyApp) that will execute TakeScreenshots.exe. But in this way, only the firefox screenshot is saved and not of the other 2. There are no exceptions. It just says "Process Complete". I guess, MyApp is not waiting for the TakeScreenshots to complete.

How can I fix this.

*[TakeScreenshots will later be placed in few remote computers & run by MyApp]*

**TakeScreenshots code:**

```
private static string[] WebDriversList = ["firefox","chrome","internetexplorer"];

private static void TakeAPic()
 {
  string url = "http://www.google.com";
  string fileNamePrefix = "Test";
  string snapSavePath = "D:\\Pics\\";

  foreach (string wd in WebDriversList)
   {
    IWebDriver NewDriver = null;
    switch (wd.ToLower())
     {
      case "firefox":
           using (NewDriver = new FirefoxDriver())
            {
             if (NewDriver != null)
              {
               CaptureScreenshot(NewDriver, url, fileNamePrefix, snapSavePath);
              }
            }
           break;
      case "chrome":
           using (NewDriver = new ChromeDriver(WebDriversPath))
            {
              if (NewDriver != null)
               {
                 CaptureScreenshot(NewDriver, url, fileNamePrefix, snapSavePath);
               }
            }
           break;
      case "internetexplorer":
           using (NewDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(WebDriversPath))
            {
             if (NewDriver != null)
              {
               CaptureScreenshot(NewDriver, url, fileNamePrefix, snapSavePath);
              }
            }
           break;
        }
      if (NewDriver != null)
       {
         NewDriver.Quit();
       }
     }
   }

private static void CaptureScreenshot(IWebDriver driver,string url,string fileNamePrefix, 
            string snapSavePath)
 {
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
   Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
                ICapabilities capabilities = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).Capabilities;
   ss.SaveAsFile(snapSavePath + fileNamePrefix + "_" + capabilities.BrowserName + ".png", 
                ImageFormat.Png);            
 }
```

**MyApp code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   ExecuteTakeScreenshot();
   Console.WriteLine("PROCESS COMPLETE");
   Console.ReadKey();
 }

private static void ExecuteTakeScreenshot()
 {
   ProcessStartInfo Psi = new ProcessStartInfo("D:\\PsTools\\");
   Psi.FileName = "D:\\PsTools\\PsExec.exe";
   Psi.Arguments = "/C \\DESK101 D:\\Release\\TakeScreenshots.exe";
   Psi.UseShellExecute = false;
   Psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   Psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;   
   Process.Start(Psi).WaitForExit();
 }
```

**Update:**
It was my mistake. Initially `WebDriversPath` was assigned "WebDrivers/". When I changed it to the actual path "D:\WebDrivers\", it worked. But I still dont understand how it worked when TakeScreenshots.exe was run manually and it doesn't when run from another console

Comment: What about debugging your own code?

Comment: Why you use `@"` string syntax and put double slash \\ for directories? Remove `@` or write `D:\Release\TakeScreenshots.exe`.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In the process of doing this, it will help you debug your own issues. If you get one created and still can't solve it... come back and post your mcve, what you tried, and what the results were. Then we will be better prepared to help you.

Answer (score 1):

In similar problems I have had success with waiting for input idle first. Like this:

```
Process process = Process.Start(Psi);
process.WaitForInputIdle();
process.WaitForExit();
```

You could try this. For me it was needed to print a pdf using Adobe Reader and not close it to early afterwards.

Example:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = DestinationFile;
process.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
process.Start();
// In case of Adobe Reader the following statement is needed:
process.WaitForInputIdle();

process.WaitForExit(2000);
process.WaitForInputIdle();
process.Kill();
```

Comment: On debug, I get this exception at WaitForInputIdle `Cannot process request because the process (5600) has exited`

Comment: It sounds like your application is exiting very quickly. Maybe it does not do anything. Try and log to a file from TakeScreenshots.exe and se if the program actually does anything for other browsers than firefox.